# mobx extendObservable doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to use `extendObservable` to add more properties on observable state but it doesn't work. Below is my code

```
var store = mobx.observable({
  property: {}
});


mobx.autorun(function () {
  console.log("render:"+store.property.a);
});

store.property = {a:1};
extendObservable(store.property, {a:2});
store.property.a=3;
```

The output is:

```
render:undefined
render:1
```

I initialised a store with a `property` object. I want to add `a` as a observable state under `property` but I didn't get the `autorun` executed after using `extendObservable` method. I expected the value 3 got printed but it didn't. What's wrong with my code? Is it the correct way to use `extendObservable` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read why this doesn't work in the [**Common pitfalls & best practices**](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html) section of the documentation:

> MobX observable objects do not detect or react to property assignments
>   that weren't declared observable before. So MobX observable objects
>   act as records with predefined keys. You can use
>   `extendObservable(target, props)` to introduce new observable
>   properties to an object. However object iterators like `for .. in` or
>   `Object.keys()` won't react to this automatically. If you need a
>   dynamically keyed object, for example to store users by id, create
>   observable _map_s using
>   [**observable.map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html).

So instead of using `extendObservable` on an observable object, you could just add a new key to an observable map.

**Example**

```
var store = mobx.observable({
  property: mobx.observable.map({})
});

mobx.autorun(function () {
  console.log('render:' + store.property.get('a'));
});

store.property.set('a', 2);

setTimeout(function () {
  store.property.set('a', 3);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this page https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html very minutely. There are some laws onto the usage of dynamic properties added using `extendObservable`. The one which you are "observing" (pun intended) is documented on that page in the section **Incorrect: using not yet existing observable object properties**. The right way to do this is also mentioned in the subsequent section.

Basically, your tracking functions must use the `get` method of the observable to ensure it gets invoked again on state mutations. The fixed code is -

```
mobx.autorun(function () {
  console.log("render:"+store.property.get("a"));
});

extendObservable(store.property, {a:2});
store.property.set("a", 3);
```

So you need to use `get`/`set` with `extendObservable` extended objects.